# How can I setup servers with no HDD to boot Windows Server via network?

Tags: networking, boot, windows-server

How can I setup servers with no HDD to boot Windows Server via network?

The servers has a CD-ROM drive, and I also have some servers with loads of hard drives which could function as network storage.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set up computer to boot from a network drive](http://superuser.com/questions/288093/how-to-set-up-computer-to-boot-from-a-network-drive), [Booting off windows image through network](http://superuser.com/questions/520000/booting-off-windows-image-through-network?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the BIOS supports network or PXE boot you can do that.  As long as they have enough RAM to hold your OS plus function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is attainable, but challenging.  Windows Server 2008's recommended minimum is 10gb of disk space just to install.  So whatever you're going to do, you'll need that much RAM just for the OS, on top of RAM to be used by the OS once it boots.

The entire hard disk image has to be pulled down across the network via the PXE boot **before** you ever see a Windows logo.

Also remember that anything you do and anything you install on such a box, once it boots, IS NOT SAVED because it's all in RAM.  Getting applications into the boot image is really tricky!